# Multiple .htaccess rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm getting the grip of .htaccess, but now i'm stuck in a situation where there's multiple redirects needed.

- website/werknemers/5
- website/lijst/5

Those links should work, redirecting from

- index.php?page=werknemers&klant=5
- index.php?page=lijst&lijst=5

I'm using the following .htaccess, which is working! **but only the one's i put at the top of the document**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&klant=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&lijst=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Web servers don't work that way.

Comment: Okay.. Could you please explain what i'm doing wrong? Your comment is not very constructive :)

Comment: Your match patterns are **exactly the same**. How is the server supposed to tell them apart?

Comment: Would this be a better solution? to specify which page it's on?

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&lijst=$2 [L]`
`RewriteRule ^werknemers/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&klant=$2 [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your patterns are exactly the same, there is no difference between the first and second rules, so the first always matches and you will always get the `klant` query string *no matter what*. You can hardcode the page names if that's the only thing that's different:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^werknemers/(.*)$ index.php?page=werknemers&klant=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^lijst/(.*)$ index.php?page=lijst&lijst=$1 [L]
```